# One-word or a phrase for 'Time changes perspectives'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There were certain things or people of whom you assumed the worst, and yet in hindsight, you look at them differently, probably realize what they had gone through, and why they acted so. So I am looking for a single word or a phrase to be equivalent to the reflection of "How time changes your perspective about certain (mostly negative) people or events"

This one is for my tough  ex-boss, whom I had hated so vehemently while I worked with her. But after 4 good years, I realize, no one has actually inspired me to be my best, as much as she has.

Comment: You're almost there: _With the benefit of hindsight_, ...

Comment: Beware, 'cause sometimes you might be looking back with [graduation goggles](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=graduation+goggles) (or [rose-tinted lenses](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-at-see-sth-through-rose-coloured-rose-tinted-glasses)).

Answer (score 3):

I think **in retrospect** or **in hindsight** could work in given context:

> **reconsidering the past** with the knowledge one now has.

(http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+hindsight)

You could say:

> *I hated my ex-boss so vehemently while I worked with her, but **in retrospect** I realize she actually inspired me to be my best.*

Answer (score 2):

**Time heals all wounds**:

> Negative feelings eventually erode away. ([WT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time_heals_all_wounds))
>
> People eventually get over insults, injuries, and hatreds. ([*New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GAzOg4eQl2YC&pg=PA56&q=%22time%20heals%20all%20wounds%22#v=onepage&q=%22time%20heals%20all%20wounds%22&f=false))

The phrase usually refers to emotional, not physical, "injuries." So an example sentence might be:

> He treated me badly back then, but time heals all wounds.  I'm fine now.

Comment: Or the corrollary phrase: "He treated me badly back then, but time wounds all heels. I'm fine now."

Answer (score 1):

***Time works wonders.***

> *Prov.* The passing of time can resolve many problems.
>
> *I thought I would never forgive my ex-husband for leaving me, but now, ten years later, I feel pretty well disposed toward him. Time works wonders. You'll change your mind eventually. Time works wonders.*
>
> *[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ss2QboIOsPgC&q=mcgraw%20hill%20%22time%20works%20wonders%22&dq=mcgraw%20hill%20%22time%20works%20wonders%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAGoVChMIiuLAhrn8yAIVwqMeCh23jwW6)*

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***Youth is wasted on the young*** and ***If youth but knew; if age but could***.

> Youth cannot believe the world to be what it is, and age, when it has realized the truth, has no longer the energy to act on it. [Flowers of Speech](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Qyo4AQAAIAAJ&q=%22if+youth+but+knew+if+age+but+could%22&dq=%22if+youth+but+knew+if+age+but+could%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwjbnKqe1_zIAhXIuhQKHd-iCUU)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+youth+but+knew%2CWe+grow+too+soon+old%2Cyouth+is+wasted+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIf%20youth%20but%20knew%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWe%20grow%20too%20soon%20old%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyouth%20is%20wasted%20on%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

A proverb says that **a wise man changes his mind sometimes, a fool never**.

> What means that It is wise to reconsider your plans, ideas, actions in
>   the light of new information rather than to blindly stick to an
>   earlier decision.

Answer (score 0):

"Time changes/heals/fixes everythig" could be considered.

> This one is for my tough ex-boss, whom I had hated so vehemently while
>   I worked with her. But after 4 good years, ***time changes everything including my hatred*** towards her. I realize, no one has
>   actually inspired me to be my best, as much as she has.

You could use a variety of verbs in place of "change", for example, ***heal, fix***, etc. It seems that using "changes" is most popular with the number of Google hits, 198,000, followed by "heals", 183,000 and "fixes", 31,600.